# A more elegant way to cast in base groovy

Tags: java, groovy, casting

I always seem to be needing to cast values in the params object in order to perform a `.equals` but it never feels right.  If i use the `parseXXX` methods I also have to protect myself when the value is empty. It seems like there would be a better way to handle this in a dynamic language like Groovy.  Has anyone found a different way that feels more like Groovy and less like Java?  I could build a utility class to clean this up but **I am looking for some built in functionality so please don't suggest additional libraries**.

Example:

```
def intValue = (params.intValue)? Integer.parseInt(params.intValue) :null

Things.each{ thing -> 
    if (thing.intValue.equals(intValue)){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using the [Type Conversion Methods](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.12%20Simple%20Type%20Converters):

```
def intValue = params.int('myparam')
```

> ...there are also methods for `boolean`, `long`, `char`, `short` and so on. Each of these methods are null safe and safe from any parsing errors
>   so you don't have to perform any addition checks on the parameters.

Comment: Excellent!  I knew there had to be a Groovier way.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most 'Groovy way' is as follows:

```
params.intValue as Integer == thing.intValue
```

Comment: @Michael This one throws `NumberFormatException` on malformed `params.intValue` as your original code did, but that may not be what you really want -- the other answer doesn't has this problem :).